# How to highlight all matching words in a paragraph when searching multiple words in react

Tags: javascript, regex, algorithm, jsx, text-parsing

I have a JSX element that displays a search result and the result has the matching search term highlighted wherever it appears in the result. For instance if `searchTerm = 'hello world'` and `result.text = 'foo bar hello world it is hello'`, it will be highlighted like so: 'foo bar **hello world** it is hello'. This solution only works for perfect matches however.

```
// JSX that displays a search result with matches highlighted
<div style={{ whiteSpace: 'normal' }}>
    {highlightMatch(documentationIndexState.searchTerm, result.text)}
</div>

// highlight function
function highlightMatch(searchTerm: string, text: string) {
    const parts = text.split(new RegExp(`(${searchTerm})`, 'gi'));
    return (
        <span>
            {' '}
            {parts.map((part, i) => (
                <span
                    key={i}
                    style={
                        part.toLowerCase() === searchTerm.toLowerCase() ? { fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'yellow' } : {}
                    }
                >
                    {part}
                </span>
            ))}{' '}
        </span>
    );
}
```

How could I modify the regex to have any matching word be highlighted in the text? So the searchTerm would have to be split up into individual words and the resulting highlights would be 'foo bar **hello world** it is **hello**'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a modified `highlightMatch()` function using plan JavaScript so that it can be shown here in the JS snippet -- you can convert that back into TypeScript:

```js
function highlightMatch(searchTerm, text) {
    const escapedTerm = searchTerm.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
    const regex = new RegExp('\\b' + escapedTerm + '\\b', 'gi');
    text = text.replace(regex, m => '<span class="highlightText">' + m + '</span>');
    return ( {text} );
}

const text = 'foo bar hello world it is hello';
const searchTerm = 'hello world';
let result = highlightMatch(searchTerm, text);
console.log(result);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
```

```css
.highlightText {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

**Notes:**

- the search term needs to be escaped, so that chars special to regex can be searched literally: `/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g`
- the search regex is created dynamically with the escaped search term
- the search term uses `\b` word boundaries to avoid false hits, such as text `highlighted` with text `light` (remove the word boundaries if you want to highlight text within words)
- the `.replace()` encloses the matched text in a span with class `highlightText`

**UPDATE:** The OP updated and changed the question to search for all search terms, not the search string. This is reflected here:

```js
function highlightMatch(searchTerm, text) {
    const escapedTerms = searchTerm.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&').split(/\s+/);
    const regex = new RegExp('\\b' + escapedTerms.join('|') + '\\b', 'gi');
    text = text.replace(regex, m => '<span class="highlightText">' + m + '</span>');
    return ( text );
}

const text = 'foo bar hello world it is hello';
const searchTerm = 'hello world';
let result = highlightMatch(searchTerm, text);
console.log(result);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
```

```css
.highlightText {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

**UPDATE 2:** JSX version

```
function highlightMatch(searchTerm: string, text: string) {
  const escapedTerms = searchTerm.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&').split(/\s+/);
  const regex = new RegExp('\\b' + escapedTerms.join('|') + '\\b', 'gi');
  const parts = text
    .replace(regex, m => `\x01${m}\x02`)
    .split(/(\x01[^\x02]+\x02)/);
  return (
    <span>
    {parts.map(part => (
      //part[0] === '\x01' ? {part} : {part})}
      <span
        style = {
          part[0] === '\x01' ? { fontWeight: 'bold', backgroundColor: 'yellow' } : {}
        }
      >
      {part.replace(/[\x01\x02]/g, '')}
      </span>
    ))}
    </span>
  );
}
```

The JSX version is more complex due to the fact that you can't return HTML text in a function, you have to return an HTML object. Steps:

- parts is constructed with the regex, where each found search term is enclosed in `\x01` and `\x02`, then split with capture group, e.g. the split pattern is included in the returned array
- the HTML object is constructed by walking through the parts in a similar way to the OP's original code

***Learn more about regex:*** https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex

Comment: i ran the code snippet and it doesnt seem to work. the first occurrence of 'hello world' is highlighted correctly but the second 'hello' is skipped

Comment: I answered you original question where stated 'foo bar **hello world** it is hello', e.g. search only for the full search term, not each search word.

Comment: @xXx_emo_girl_xXx: I added one more code snippet that reflects your changed mind, please check.

Comment: this solution does not return a JSX object

Comment: @xXx_emo_girl_xXx: I was simply using the code snippet tool here to demo, which does not support JSX. It's easy to return a JSX object. Change the last line to: `return ( {text.replace(regex, m => '<span class="highlightText">' + m + '</span>')} );`

Comment: that presents errors over `text` for Parsing error: ',' expected.eslint and `m` for Parameter 'm' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts

Comment: Did you change the function definition back to this? `function highlightMatch(searchTerm: string, text: string)`

Comment: yes i changed those already

Comment: Please see UPDATE 2

Comment: update 2 still returns a string. in order to return a JSX i believe you need to wrap it in something like <span> like what is done in my code example for `highlightMatch`

Comment: I updated UPDATE 2

Comment: the solution itself is flawed as the '<span class...' stuff just gets dumped as a string and does not apply formatting. i will be closing this question but thank you for your effort!

Comment: That is because you either need to define the css (as in the example), or change the class attribute to a stye attribute. I updated UPDATE 2 again...

Comment: update provided does not compile. had to change to `text = text.replace(regex, m => "<span style={fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'yellow'}>" + m + '</span>');`    and in doing so it still displays HTML wrapped around text instead of actual highlighting like the example code i provided

Comment: Check the updated UPDATE 2, this JSX should return a proper HTML object now

Answer (score 0):

I am new to react, but maybe this will help: `(hello)|(world)`.

Add it to this line: `new RegExp('(hello)|(world)')`

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/H6JWmM/1)

Comment: how would i plug in the pipe logic into the highlight function?

Comment: This would also catch `worldcup` and other compound words, better use `new RegExp('\\b(hello|world)\\b')`